# Texstudio show list of defined labels when defining a new label

Tags: cross-referencing, texstudio

When I define a new label the autocomplete feature only suggests `\label{key}`. I would like to know if there is any way to get a list of all defined labels, just like when using `\ref`, which gives a list of all label to choose from. This is bothersome, because I have to open the structure view to find out what I want to name my new label (usually `eq1`, `eq2,` and so on). Is there a way to get this list while defining a new label?

Comment: The point of `\label` is to give a *new* label. TeXstudio automatically detects a duplicate label. If you use labels like `eq1` and `eq2` you don't really use the cross-referencing system to its full potential. (If you put one between those two are you renaming the second one?) It would be better to name them for what they stand.

Comment: No, I'm not using labels like that. eq1, eq2 and so on are just random labels I add where needed, it doesn't mean I add eq1 and eq2 to the equations actually labeled (1) and (2). The point is that there is no way of knowing if a label has already been used until you fully type it and get the underline telling you it was already defined. In winedt for instance, when you type \label{ you get a full list of all defined labels, so you can easily type a new name and see if it is already taken.

Comment: For now my solution is to use \ref{ to see the full list of already defined lables, and be able to type a new one. Then I go back and change \ref to \label once the new label is defined...cumbersome, but it's working for now. It would still be better to see the full list of labels as I type \label{ so I know I'm actually defining a new one. I thought this functionality would be available in texstudio. I like it very much though, so I can live with this limitation for now